# Can I erase my preinstalled Windows and use the serial number elsewhere?

Tags: windows

I have recently purchased a Windows laptop with the intention of installing Linux on it.  My question is about the existing Windows installation (note that as an ultrabook, my shiny new computer does not have a CD drive, so I don't know what the recovery media is).

I would rather not dual boot, but will have occasional reasons to use Windows, so I see 2 options, both of which involve a VM:

1. Use a VM to point to the Windows partition [as in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168156/how-to-use-a-real-partition-with-windows-7-installed-in-a-virtualbox-vm).
2. Install Linux as the only OS and then install Windows as a guest in e.g. VirtualBox.

I can see how to do #1 (and I can also see some of the potential problems that will come from multiple OSes reading the same partition).

About #2: if I completely wipe the HDD and install Linux only, can I use the Windows serial # to install a copy of Windows (8.1 to be specific) as a VM?  Or will I have some issue, even though it is a legitimate serial #?

Comment: The Windows 8.1 license you have is an [OEM license](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx), and is tied to the motherboard. The VM has different hardware, and you won't be able to activate Windows with the same license.

Comment: @and31415 That's quite irritating. If I understand you and FAQ correctly, in order to do option 2 I would have to buy a new license, b/c that copy of Windows would not be tied to any existing computer.  Is that right?

Comment: @learner That's right: a VM counts as a whole new machine. The easiest way to preserve your license is to dual boot, indeed.

Comment: @and31415 OK, thanks.  Would you mind writing this up as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## OEM license

No. The Windows 8.1 license you have is an OEM license, and is tied to the motherboard. The VM has different hardware, and counts as a whole new machine. This means you won't be able to activate Windows using the same license. The easiest way to preserve your activation is to dual boot, indeed.

> OEM licenses are single-use licenses that cannot be installed on more than one computer system, even if the original machine is no longer in use.
>
> Generally, an end user can upgrade or replace all of the hardware components on a computer—*except* the motherboard—and still retain the license for the original Microsoft OEM operating system software. If the motherboard is upgraded or replaced for reasons other than a defect, then a new computer has been created. Microsoft OEM operating system software cannot be transferred to the new computer, and the license of new operating system software is required.
>
> <sub>Source: [Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx)</sub>

## References

- [Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx)